# ESI processing not enabled error only on Product detail page Varnish and Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, nginx, varnish, centos

I am trying to hole punch a Magento having two websites setup for retail and wholesale with Varnish 4. So far I have fixed the header section not appearing error by fixing the Main Navigation provided by Smartwave Porto theme. But on wholesale site for Home page and Category pages header seems to work fine. But the product detail page shows **ESI processing not enabled** error in place of **global_messages**, **messages** and **top.links** block.

I have already tried solutions suggested in some other threads like **-p esi_syntax=0x2**

Technology Specifications are: CentOs6, Nginx, Varnish 4, Magento 1.9.

It seems like the Turpentine extensions' EsiController->getBlock() method is not returning a proper response to varnish or may be these ESI blocks are not getting parsed at all. How can I debug further?

The multi-store setup works based on the below changes made to index.php file:

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'dev.domain.com':
    case 'www.dev.domain.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'retail_shop_code';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'shop.domain.com':
    case 'www.shop.domain.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'wholesale_shop_code';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Just may be above code has something to do with varnish not processing ESI correctly?

Comment: What happens if you do the same with Env variables in the htaccess instead of in the index.php file?

Comment: @mbalparda thank you for helping me out. Its fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varnish 4 does not support `-p esi_syntax=`, instead you have to use `-p feature=`

```
-p feature=+esi_disable_xml_check,+esi_ignore_other_elements
```

`esi_disable_xml_check`, "Don't check of body looks like XML", "Allow ESI processing on any kind of object"

`esi_ignore_other_elements`, "Ignore non-esi XML-elements","Allows syntax errors in the XML"

**ESI processing not enabled** error is related to php/template error, opcode cache issues, or your layout files in wrong place/read order.

try to change settings per block reference in `turpentine_esi.xml` or in store layout file directly, it can be `esi|ajax` method also.

Comment: thank you for specifying the different syntax between V3 and V4. In my case it turned out to be a broken php code in footer section. which was probably the cause of **ESI processing not enabled** error. As Varnish was seeing a invalid xml. So I have added `esi_disable_xml_check` to varnish config also.

Comment: great, you can mark this answer as a solution then ;)

Comment: I tried to upvote ur answer but its not doing the trick as I have less than 15 points. Is there any other way?

Comment: i think you can mark this as answer no matter how many points you have, this was your question.

Comment: Already did. It will not show publicly until I earn 15 reputation points. It's recorded though.